# Can I load both images and video in the same pixi.js Loader

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am able to load a set of images into pixi.js using the following code:

```
let preloadAssetsData = data.map(function(value) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080' + value.url;
});
PIXI.loader.reset();
PIXI.loader.add(preloadAssetsData).load(function() {
    console.log('All assets loaded');
});
```

where `data` is an array of image URLs. However, this seems to be working only for images and not for video files (.mp4).

Edited 8/30/2016: The reason I think it is not working for video is because when I attempt to load the texture for the image using this code:

```
let texture = PIXI.loader.resources['http://localhost:8080' + url].texture;
texture.baseTexture.on('loaded', function() {
    texture.baseTexture.source.pause();
});
```

I encounter a JavaScript error: `read property 'baseTexture' of undefined`. However, when I load a texture for the video using `PIXI.Texture.fromVideo(...)`, I don't have a problem. But then, I am not leveraging a pre-loaded resource, as in the case of images.

```
let texture = PIXI.Texture.fromVideo('http://localhost:8080' + url);
texture.baseTexture.on('loaded', function() {
    texture.baseTexture.source.pause();
});
```

Comment: I don't see why not. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Karmacon Yes, I added more details about the error I am running into. When I googled for more information about this issue, it appears the PIXI.loader handles only images. I could be wrong or it could also be about an older version of PIXI. I am using v3.

Comment: @WebUser I have never used it for videos so far, so I can't say for certain. But this suggest that it does: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/16450-pixi-loading-video-files/ also the html5gamedevs.com is your best bet to find good answers regarding PIXI.js, you can just try to search additional info.
Oh and the loader is heavily based on this: https://github.com/englercj/resource-loader